# Mixpanel error: "mixpanel" object not initialized. Please help me find out this error?

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

[image: Here is the image of ERROR]

Mixpanel error: "mixpanel" object not initialized. Ensure you are using the latest version of the Mixpanel JS Library along with the snippet we provide.

Comment: So, are you using the latest version?

Comment: I am just practising basic javascript and not using any Mixpanel.

Comment: You're going to have to provide a lot more context then. It's completely unclear what you're asking

Comment: I am just curious why this mixpanel error is coming when I check my code output on google chrome console.

Comment: @phil It is clear. OP got a problem out of nowhere and was clueless, looking for help. And so did I get it today. Apparently neither of us is able to provide steps to reproduce. Otherwise we would probably have been able to solve the problem without asking anyone. Does asking for help on SO mean that you are required to know more than you do? Besides, if this question is off-topic, then what is the topic?

Comment: @DipankarBARUA Just got this error too, it was caused by one of Chrome Extensions.

Comment: Thanks @DanielSitarz  I had this very same problem and I solved it disabling "Page Ruler" Chrome Extensions.

Comment: same problem here and i solved disabling "Page Ruler" Chrome Extensions. Thanks @RogerRussel  !!

Comment: Confirmed, the chrome plugin "Page Ruler" generate the error, disabling it will solve the problem. I write it in the store page too

Comment: @user776686 no, it is **not** clear. OP gave no context about what they were doing to receive the error. This is a programming Q&A site so I think it's safe to assume questions revolve around some kind of code. I'm glad you all got the problem solved but this post is not a good question for this site. It's a misplaced bug report for a 3rd party browser extension at best. The `chrome-extension` message in the error should have been enough to point OP in the right direction.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541556

Comment: @pang how it is possible duplicate if this was asked on day before?

Comment: @RogerRussel https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280726/1402846 | https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55251/204869 | https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643/204869 | https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182868/204869 | https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294000/1402846

Comment: Thanks, @DanielSitarz  for the giving the answer.