# mixpanel-2-latest.min.js:9 Mixpanel error: "mixpanel" object not initialized

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

> mixpanel-2-latest.min.js:9 Mixpanel error: "mixpanel" object not initialized. Ensure you are using the latest version of the Mixpanel JS Library along with the snippet we provide.

From the last couple of days, I am seeing this error in the console when I do inspect element in my Google Chrome. I am using the latest Chrome version 64. I am not using `mixpanel`. It's also showing up if I open any public website. Any idea how to resolve this error?

[image: Screenshot of Chrome with error in developer console]

Answer (score 62):

Check your extensions, for me it was 'Page Ruler' (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-ruler/jlpkojjdgbllmedoapgfodplfhcbnbpn?hl=nl) that caused this error. Systematically disable all extensions until the error does not occur anymore.

Comment: Also for me the plugin Page Ruler was the reason for this error. I'm asking myself how that is possible that we get an error in console of a website due to a plugin we use.

Comment: @Asqan thankfully we did get that error, otherwise many people wouldn't have realized that this extension has gone rouge and sending confidential information.

Comment: 'Page Ruler'  for me, too

Comment: @Pablo could you give more info about it? tks

Comment: Yesterday when working on a angularjs project, I pressed F5 and my js console showed me an error regarding Mixpanel that could not be loaded. At first I though this was a dependency of mine, but when I could not find it, I did a google search and found this page. Following @spassvogel's link I read the reviews and I informed myself about what Maxipanel does.

Comment: @Asqan This actually makes a lot of sense, go into your console, look at the top of it, right below the nav (you know the one with the "element", "console", etc. tabs), you'll notice that there's the word "top". Click on it. Please share any feelings of amazement below.

Comment: @Asqan If you didn't get it, the console you view shows you each and every console log thrown by anything that can throw a log at it, extensions included. I'm guessing this is for debug reasons. Clicking on one of the options below top will lead you to only seeing logs from that extension.

Comment: had this issue yesterday with "Page Ruler"

Comment: Unchecking the checkbox "Send Anonymous Usage Statistics" resolved this for me.

Answer (score 11):

I started getting this error out of the blue. It was the chrome extension PageRuler. I trashed PageRuler and the error went away.

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, you can go to Page Ruler's options menu, and uncheck "Send Anonymous Usage Statistics".
This will enable you to continue using the extensions without seeing the error message.

Answer (score 5):

That's correct. [The Page ruler plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-ruler/jlpkojjdgbllmedoapgfodplfhcbnbpn?) is the one who cause the console error "Mixpanel error: "mixpanel" object not initialized".
Disable it and all good to go

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything to the three existing answers that say the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

"Free Video Downloader" is another cause.

Answer (score 2):

Check your extensions, for me, it was 'Page Ruler'.

**No need to remove 'Page Ruler', Instead of removing do the following...**

Page Ruler's options menu, and uncheck "Send Anonymous Usage Statistics".

Answer (score 1):

I checked all given answere in here. All sayed to disable the **"Send Anonymous Usage Statistics"** checkbox in the settings....

I think **hiding a problem is not solving a problem**. Since there were a newer version of PageRuler (*i had `2.1.2`, newest is currently `2.1.3`*) I deinstalled the old one, reinstalled the new one and from now on, no matter if I send stats or not, error doesn't appaers anymore.