# Mixpanel error: "mixpanel" object not initialized

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

I am getting the below error.

I am using Angular - I have not imported a mix panel library - if I do a search I cannot find this.

Why am I getting this error/how can  get rid of it?

> Mixpanel error: "mixpanel" object not initialized. Ensure you are
>   using the latest version of the Mixpanel JS Library along with the
>   snippet we provide.

Comment: See this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541556/jsmixpanel-2-latest-min-js9-mixpanel-error-mixpanel-object-not-initialized - it solved it for me.

Answer (score 175):

If you are not using mixpanel in your code, you should check whether it is one of your extensions.

In my case it was the PageRuler extension and started happening only today.

Comment: Thanks, this happened after updating Chrome to version 64.0.3282.140

Comment: Removed page ruler

Comment: The creator of the extension was notified... https://github.com/wrakky/page-ruler/issues/103

Comment: This is a tracking library... How much information is a chrome addin able to track? i.e. can they see hostnames, mouse moves, clicks, etc?

Comment: I just checked, and yep, it was Page Ruler for me too, but i didn't remove or disable it. I just unchecked 'Send Anonymous Usage Statistics' option under the extension options, since @ZachSmith mentioned that its a tracking library. Now there is no error.

Comment: Also Page Ruler ^^

Answer (score 81):

**Check your extensions, for me it was 'Page Ruler'**

["https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-ruler/jlpkojjdgbllmedoapgfodplfhcbnbpn?hl=nl"] that caused this error.

Disable all extensions until the error does not occur anymore.

Comment: Same issue with Page Ruler... Worked fine without it. Why would an extension cause an issue with a random JS library? Poor extension code or poor library code?

Comment: @JakeWilson This happened after updating Chrome to version 64.0.3282.140